# StreamReader alternative that treats null char (\0) as line ending

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have a client program that receives streaming XML messages from a remote server. These streams provide real-time updates to various sporting events, and it runs forever; even when there are no updates to transmit, it still sends a keep-alive message every 45 seconds.

The service in question has two feeds with different details. The first feed terminates each XML message with a carriage-return/line-feed pair (0d, 0a), which means it's very easy to consume with StreamReader. EG:

```
using (TcpClient Client = new TcpClient(this.Host, this.Port))
{
   using (NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream())
   {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      {
         String message = reader.ReadLine();
         ProcessMessage(message);
      }
   }
}
```

The second feed, however, does not terminate with CR/LF but only with null characters (\0), which StreamReader.ReadLine() does not treat as the end of a line, so it blocks forever waiting for something that will never come.

I can't write this to a file first, and I can't make the company providing the feeds change anything because it's already being consumed by others.

Is there an alternative to StreamReader that will consider a null char to be an end-of-line terminator?

Comment: A couple of interesting solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667771/c-sharp-streamreader-readline-need-to-pick-up-line-terminators). A lexer parser and global replace.

Comment: Just write your own Stream class, similar to BufferedStream, that translates '\0' to \r\n.

Comment: Probably better to implement a custom Reader than a Stream.

Comment: @hans-passant Do you know of any example implementations of something like a BufferedStream? I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

CustomStreamReader class - terminates on either '\0' or '\r\n'. I've tested with both a File-based stream and a MemoryStream, I imagine a NetworkStream shouldn't really be significantly different.... let me know how you go!

I've also included the significant code from my TestHarness at the end of this post, I had some extreme weirdness with stream positions being set to max prior to the read when using the MemoryStream.

I can't really take much credit, most of this was just extracting the necessary parts from the existing StreamReader from the Microsoft Reference Source... a couple of hours or so to modify and test successfully.

**CustomStreamReader**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StreamReaderOverride
{
    public class CustomStreamReader : StreamReader
    {
        private int charPos;

        private int charLen;

        private int byteLen;

        private Encoding encoding;

        private bool _isBlocked;

        private byte[] byteBuffer;

        private Decoder decoder;

        private int bytePos;

        private bool _checkPreamble;

        private bool _detectEncoding;

        private Stream stream;

        private volatile Task _asyncReadTask;

        private char[] charBuffer;

        private byte[] _preamble;

        private bool _closable;

        public bool EndOfStream;

        private int _maxCharsPerBuffer;

        public CustomStreamReader(Stream stream): this(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, DefaultBufferSize, false)
        {

        }

        public CustomStreamReader(string path): this(path, Encoding.UTF8, true, DefaultBufferSize, false)
        {

        }

        public CustomStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen): base(stream, Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, bufferSize, false)
        {
            if (stream == null || encoding == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException((stream == null) ? "stream" : "encoding");
            }
            if (!stream.CanRead)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(GetResourceString("Argument_StreamNotReadable"));
            }
            if (bufferSize <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize", GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedPosNum"));
            }
            this.Init(stream, encoding, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, bufferSize, leaveOpen);
        }

        internal CustomStreamReader(string path, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool checkHost): base(path, Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, bufferSize)
        {
            if (path == null || encoding == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException((path == null) ? "path" : "encoding");
            }
            if (path.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyPath"));
            }
            if (bufferSize <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize", GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedPosNum"));
            }
            Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, false);
            this.Init(stream, encoding, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, bufferSize, false);
        }

        internal static int DefaultBufferSize
        {
            get
            {
                return 1024;
            }
        }


        private void Init(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)
        {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.encoding = encoding;
            this.decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
            if (bufferSize < 128)
            {
                bufferSize = 128;
            }
            this.byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            this._maxCharsPerBuffer = encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize);
            this.charBuffer = new char[this._maxCharsPerBuffer];
            this.byteLen = 0;
            this.bytePos = 0;
            this._detectEncoding = detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks;
            this._preamble = encoding.GetPreamble();
            this._checkPreamble = (this._preamble.Length > 0);
            this._isBlocked = false;
            this._closable = !leaveOpen;
        }

        private void CheckAsyncTaskInProgress()
        {
            Task asyncReadTask = this._asyncReadTask;
            if (asyncReadTask != null && !asyncReadTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(GetResourceString("InvalidOperation_AsyncIOInProgress"));
            }
        }

        public string ReadLineOrNullString()
        {            
            if (this.stream == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            this.CheckAsyncTaskInProgress();
            if (this.charPos == this.charLen && this.ReadBuffer() == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
            int num;
            char c;
            while (true)
            {
                num = this.charPos;
                do
                {
                    c = this.charBuffer[num];
                    if (c == '\r' || c == '\n' || c == '\0')
                    {
                        goto IL_4A;
                    }

                    num++;
                }
                while (num < this.charLen);
                num = this.charLen - this.charPos;
                if (stringBuilder == null)
                {
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(num + 80);
                }
                stringBuilder.Append(this.charBuffer, this.charPos, num);
                if (this.ReadBuffer() <= 0)
                {
                    goto Block_11;
                }
            }
        IL_4A:
            string result;
            if (stringBuilder != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(this.charBuffer, this.charPos, num - this.charPos);
                result = stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                result = new string(this.charBuffer, this.charPos, num - this.charPos);
            }
            this.charPos = num + 1;
            if ((c == '\r' && (this.charPos < this.charLen || this.ReadBuffer() > 0) && this.charBuffer[this.charPos] == '\n'))
            {
                this.charPos++;
            }
            if (this.charPos >= this.charLen)
            {
                this.EndOfStream = true;
            }
            return result;
        Block_11:
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        internal virtual int ReadBuffer()
        {
            this.charLen = 0;
            this.charPos = 0;
            if (!this._checkPreamble)
            {
                this.byteLen = 0;
            }
            while (true)
            {
                if (this._checkPreamble)
                {
                    int num = this.stream.Read(this.byteBuffer, this.bytePos, this.byteBuffer.Length - this.bytePos);
                    if (num == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    this.byteLen += num;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.byteLen = this.stream.Read(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteBuffer.Length);
                    if (this.byteLen == 0)
                    {
                        goto Block_5;
                    }
                }
                this._isBlocked = (this.byteLen < this.byteBuffer.Length);
                if (!this.IsPreamble())
                {
                    if (this._detectEncoding && this.byteLen >= 2)
                    {
                        this.DetectEncoding();
                    }
                    this.charLen += this.decoder.GetChars(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteLen, this.charBuffer, this.charLen);
                }
                if (this.charLen != 0)
                {
                    goto Block_9;
                }
            }
            if (this.byteLen > 0)
            {
                this.charLen += this.decoder.GetChars(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteLen, this.charBuffer, this.charLen);
                this.bytePos = (this.byteLen = 0);
            }
            return this.charLen;
        Block_5:
            return this.charLen;
        Block_9:
            return this.charLen;
        }

        private bool IsPreamble()
        {
            if (!this._checkPreamble)
            {
                return this._checkPreamble;
            }
            int num = (this.byteLen >= this._preamble.Length) ? (this._preamble.Length - this.bytePos) : (this.byteLen - this.bytePos);
            int i = 0;
            while (i < num)
            {
                if (this.byteBuffer[this.bytePos] != this._preamble[this.bytePos])
                {
                    this.bytePos = 0;
                    this._checkPreamble = false;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                this.bytePos++;
            }
            if (this._checkPreamble && this.bytePos == this._preamble.Length)
            {
                this.CompressBuffer(this._preamble.Length);
                this.bytePos = 0;
                this._checkPreamble = false;
                this._detectEncoding = false;
            }
            return this._checkPreamble;
        }

        private void DetectEncoding()
        {
            if (this.byteLen < 2)
            {
                return;
            }
            this._detectEncoding = false;
            bool flag = false;
            if (this.byteBuffer[0] == 254 && this.byteBuffer[1] == 255)
            {
                this.encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(true, true);
                this.CompressBuffer(2);
                flag = true;
            }
            else if (this.byteBuffer[0] == 255 && this.byteBuffer[1] == 254)
            {
                if (this.byteLen < 4 || this.byteBuffer[2] != 0 || this.byteBuffer[3] != 0)
                {
                    this.encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true);
                    this.CompressBuffer(2);
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.encoding = new UTF32Encoding(false, true);
                    this.CompressBuffer(4);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            else if (this.byteLen >= 3 && this.byteBuffer[0] == 239 && this.byteBuffer[1] == 187 && this.byteBuffer[2] == 191)
            {
                this.encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                this.CompressBuffer(3);
                flag = true;
            }
            else if (this.byteLen >= 4 && this.byteBuffer[0] == 0 && this.byteBuffer[1] == 0 && this.byteBuffer[2] == 254 && this.byteBuffer[3] == 255)
            {
                this.encoding = new UTF32Encoding(true, true);
                this.CompressBuffer(4);
                flag = true;
            }
            else if (this.byteLen == 2)
            {
                this._detectEncoding = true;
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                this.decoder = this.encoding.GetDecoder();
                this._maxCharsPerBuffer = this.encoding.GetMaxCharCount(this.byteBuffer.Length);
                this.charBuffer = new char[this._maxCharsPerBuffer];
            }
        }

        private void CompressBuffer(int n)
        {
            InternalBlockCopy(this.byteBuffer, n, this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteLen - n);
            this.byteLen -= n;
        }


        [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries"), SecuritySafeCritical]
        internal static string GetResourceString(string key)
        {
            return GetResourceFromDefault(key);
        }

        [SecurityCritical]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        internal static extern string GetResourceFromDefault(string key);

        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        internal static extern void InternalBlockCopy(Array src, int srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, int dstOffsetBytes, int byteCount);
    }
}
```

**TestHarness**

```
        string testString = "A String with a newline here\r\n and a null here\0 then another newline\r\n then another null\0";

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\testfile123.txt");

        writer.Write(testString);

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();            
        writer.Dispose();

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        List<string> strings2 = new List<string>();

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testString));

        using (CustomStreamReader reader = new CustomStreamReader(memStream))
        {
            bool setPos = true;
            while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                if (setPos) 
                { 
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    setPos = false;
                }                    

                strings.Add(reader.ReadLineOrNullString());
            }
        }

        using (CustomStreamReader reader = new CustomStreamReader(@"c:\temp\testfile123.txt"))
        {
            bool setPos = true;
            while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                /*if (setPos)
                {
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    setPos = false;
                }*/

                strings2.Add(reader.ReadLineOrNullString());
            }
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow code to find custom end char:

```
using (TcpClient Client = new TcpClient(this.Host, this.Port))
{
   using (NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream())
   {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
      //just use the bellow code like(from sr.EndOfStream to reader.Peek()>=0)
      while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
      {
         String message = reader.ReadLine();
         ProcessMessage(message);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images. It cannot be read by screen readers, it cannot be indexed by search engines, it's useless. Just post it as text formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(txtCSfileName.Text.Trim()))
        {
            while (read.Peek() > 0)
            {
                listSMtext.Items.Add(read.ReadLine());
            }
        };
```

Use the above code to find custom end char.